# docker execute command when opening the container cli

Tags: docker

Anyone know how can I execute a command when I open the cli of a container from the interface in docker?
[descriptive image where the button is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muvpw.png)

Answer (score 0):

the cli button should open a terminal session for you, once the window is open and you can access the terminal, you can use it a a normal Linux terminal